# play framework get parameter in url with dash

Tags: scala, url, playframework, playframework-2.0

In the url the parameter is like this:
`email=TTT&first-name=XXX&last-name=YYY`

So how could I get the parameter value from the url?

I know if I use the function

```
def widget(email: String) = Action{ request =>
```

I want to show all the parameters.

I could get the email . But I cannot name the value as `last-name` since dashes cannot be in a name of a variable. So how could I get the value of lastname like this? (Suppose I could not change the link since I grab the link from others url)

Answer (score 0):

If you know all parameters you can create form mapping and use fold method to get all values. It works with a GET method as well. In this case it would look like this

Case class for holding url params with form mapping:

```
import play.api.data.Form
import play.api.data.Forms._

case class UrlForm(email: String, firstName: String, lastName: String)

object UrlForm {
  val form = Form[UrlForm](
    mapping(
      "email" -> text,
      "first-name" -> text,
      "last-name" -> text
    )(UrlForm.apply)(UrlForm.unapply)
  )
}
```

Controller for this form:

```
object UrlController {
  def widget() = Action { implicit request =>
      UrlForm.form.bindFromRequest.fold(
        formWithErrors => // validation errors
        urlForm => urlForm.email; urlForm.lastName //etc.
      )
  }
}
```

Notice that you are able to map url params to any type you want. String is just an example.